# Need help creating a stopwatch in C++ using system.diagnostics

Tags: c++, system.diagnostics, stopwatch

I have looked up all I need to know on how to use a stopwatch, but I can't find out how to create one. MSDN has the info `System.Diagnostics::Stopwatch` but I don't know how to include system diagnostics into my program. Is there a `#include` and/or `using namespace` that I need?

Comment: The example included with the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) wasn't clear enough?

Comment: What MSDN page are you looking at?

Comment: On that page, Retired Ninja, the example in "C++" is still c#. How do I include <System.dll>?

Comment: Example in C++ on this page is C++, and not C#. But this is C++/CLI, don't try to use StopWatch in a native code. Try this one: http://www.openflipper.org/svnrepo/CoMISo/trunk/CoMISo/Utils/StopWatch.hh

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I didn't realize the project type would make a difference. Thanks for the help Alex.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's:

```
using namespace System::Diagnostics
```

This is in **C++/cli** which has access to **c#** libraries.